# Laravel 5.2: Artisan Key Generation for Application Key not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, key, laravel-artisan

I try to Setup Laravel 5.2 on CentOS 7. When I try to generate the Application Key using the console command `php artisan key:generate` the format of the Application Key is not as expected (longer than 32 characters including the base64 encode string and thus not working in the Configuration file.The cypher in config/app.php is AES-256-CBC.

Example Output:

```
[base64:MTs0+UZ0tHljmRcFP1RpZ06aYpc1N1L3rqAx1FT+yqk=]
```

The server should have all required Extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a change made recently to the key generator. See [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/370ae34d41362c3adb61bc5304068fb68e626586) for more info.

Do you get an error stating that the key is invalid?

Comment: The console command php artisan key:generate does not generate an error  and the key is automatically being added to the .env file. Nevertheless If I access the environment I get:
RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45: 
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Comment: What's your cipher set to, should be `AES-256-CBC`. I've gotten errors like that when the cipher isn't set right or when the storage isn't writable

Answer (score 0):

put this in appServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I dont know if you have resolved this issue.. This is how I solved the same.

In the config/app.php, remove the env() and its parenthesis from the key.

eg. 'key' => env('your_key')

should change it to..

'key' => 'your_key'

I hope this helps you and others out there.